# Vertices Overlaying Object Move in Edit Mode, Object Doesn't

Tags: objects, edit-mode, vertices, keyframes

I just upgraded to Blender 4.0 and something weird is happening to my mesh. When I play the animation in *Edit Mode*, the vertices overlaying the object move but the actual object doesn't.

The second window showing the rendered object also doesn't move but I'm able to play the animation in object mode. Is this a setting issue?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I downgraded back to 3.6 which fixed the problem. Other solutions using 4.0 are still welcomed.